# Python Flask render_template invalid syntax

Tags: python, highcharts, flask

I have something strange that I can't seem to put my finger on. I have code "def" in my **init**.py that is causing a `invalid syntax` for render_template.

**__init__.py**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    i = 1
    counts = {}
    counts = build_row_count()
    chartID = 'chart_ID'
    series = {'name': 'Assets', 'data': counts.values()}
    title = {'text': 'Assets'}
    xAxis = {'categories': counts.keys()}
    yAxis = {'min': 0, 'title': {'text': 'Assets in Database', 'align': 'high'}
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT, row_count=counts, locations=get_locations(), i=i, chartID=chartID, series=series, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)
```

**Error:**

```
  File "__init__.py", line 156
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT, row_count=counts, locations=get_locations(), i=i, chartID=chartID, series=series, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The render_template is using HighCharts to render a bar chart.
Please I need some new eyes on this. It's driving me mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line prior to your return you have your syntax error

Change

```
yAxis = {'min': 0, 'title': {'text': 'Assets in Database', 'align': 'high'}
```

to close off the dictionary

```
yAxis = {'min': 0, 'title': {'text': 'Assets in Database', 'align': 'high'}}
```

Comment: you have got to be kidding me! Thanks.